# Perl v5.26x attributes like decorators/overlays. Subs pre and post processing

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand Perl attributes for subs.
For example, I expected to got as output:

```
before
middle
after
125
```

But, I have:

```
before
middle
after
middle
124
```

How to use attributes as overlays for main sub?

```
use Attribute::Handlers ;
use Data::Dumper ;

sub decorator( $\*&\@\@$$$ ):ATTR {
    my ( $package , $symbol, $referent, $attr , $data, $phase, $filename, $linenum ) = @_ ;
    my ( $before , $after ) = @$data ;

    # before processing
    $before->( @_ ) ;

    # decorated sub
    my $result = $referent->( ) ;

    # after processing
    $after->( $result )
}

sub c( $ ):decorator(
    # before
    sub( $\*&\@\@$$$ ) {
        warn 'before' ;
    } ,
    # after
    sub( $ ) {
        warn 'after' ;

        shift( @_ ) + 1
    }
) {
    warn 'middle' ;

    splice( @_ , 1 ) + 1
}

print( __PACKAGE__->c( 123 ) ) ;
```

For admins. Please, stop moking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key piece of information you're missing is that `decorator` is called once at compile time.

`decorator` will need to replace `&c` with a sub wrapping the true `&c` to get the desired result.

```perl
use Attribute::Handlers;
use Sub::Name qw( subname );

sub Wrap :ATTR(CODE) {
   my ( $pkg, $sym, $old_sub, $attr, $data, $phase, $fn, $ln ) = @_;
   my ( $before, $after ) = @$data;

   my $name = *{ $sym }{ NAME };
 
   my $new_sub = subname "wrapped_$name", sub {
      wantarray
      ? $after->(         $old_sub->( $before->( @_ ) )   )
      : $after->( scalar( $old_sub->( $before->( @_ ) ) ) )
   };

   no warnings qw( redefine );
   *$sym = $new_sub;
}
```

Tested:

```perl
sub f :Wrap(
    sub { $_[0], $_[1]+50 },
    sub { $_[0]+7000 },
) {
    $_[1]+600
}

say __PACKAGE__->f( 4 );  # 7654
```

Note: This uses the calling convention from the OP's own answer, which differs from the calling convention in the the OP's question.

Comment: Мдяяяяя....
It seems, that substitution of the main sub is single way to write wrapper using Perl attributes.
Are there better ways?

Comment: *$symbol = sub( $$ ) { $before->( @_ ) ; $after->( $referent->( @_ ) ) ; }

Comment: Better? In what way? What about the approach would you like to improve?

Comment: No, the version you put in the comment introduces bugs. It fails to maintain context, and the prototype is wrong (since the wrapped sub's prototype could be anything). It also makes stack traces less readable because you removed the use `subname`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for sceptics. Input and output filters for methods separately:

```
use Attribute::Handlers ;
use JSON ;

my $json = JSON->new( )->utf8( 0 ) ;

sub json_input:ATTR {
    my ( undef( ) , $symbol, $referent , undef( ) , $data ) = @_ ;

    $data ||= [ 0 ] ;

    *$symbol = sub {
        return $referent->( @_ ) unless @_ > 1 ;

        my ( $self , @args ) = @_ ;
        my @idxs = keys ( %{
            { +
                map {
                    do {
                        if ( $_ >= 0 ) {
                            $_
                        } else {
                            @args + $_
                        }
                    } => undef( ) ,
                } grep {
                    ( abs( $_ ) >=0 ) && ( abs( $_ ) < @args )
                } @$data
            }
        } ) ;

        $_ = $json->decode( $_ ) foreach grep { defined( $_ ) } @args[ @idxs ] ;

        $referent->( $self , @args )
    }
}
sub json_output:ATTR {
    my ( undef( ) , $symbol, $referent ) = @_ ;

    *$symbol = sub {
        my @data = $referent->( @_ ) ;

        $json->encode( @data > 1 ? \@data : @data )
    }
}
sub test
    :json_input( 0 , 2 , 10 ) # позиции аргументов, которые нужно раскодировать перед применением
    :json_output
{
    my ( $self , $data0 , $data1 , $data2 ) = @_ ;

    $data0->{ 'a' } ,
    $data2->{ 'x' }
}

print( __PACKAGE__->test( << '.' ,  << '.' ,  << '.' ) ) ; # many string arguments
{
    "a" : { "b" : "d" } ,
    "c" : "d"
}
.
{
    "d" : { "e" : "r" } ,
    "c" : "d"
}
.
{
    "x" : { "e" : "r" } ,
    "c" : "d"
}
.

+1
```

Just take a look at `sub test:json_input( 0 , 2 ):json_output`.

Answer (score -2):

```
... the prototype is wrong and it never would to work... Let's try.
```

It is the canvas or scratch. The idea.

The version I've accepted for now:

```
sub decorator( $\*&\@\@$$$ ):ATTR {
    my ( undef( ) , $symbol, $referent , undef( ) , $data ) = @_ ;
    my ( $before , $after ) = @$data ;

    *$symbol = sub {
        $after->( $referent->( $before->( @_ ) ) )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a copy of what I posted which doesn't add anything except a bug: It removes the context preservation. It also removes the naming of the anon sub, which makes for worse stack traces.

Comment: Оно рабоъётайет.

Comment: No. It's easy to show it doesn't work. /// Take  `sub f { "a", "b", "c" }  my $x = f();` This returns `c`.  But if you wrap it with your buggy code, it passes `"a", "b", "c"` to "after" instead of `"c"`. /// Take `use Carp qw( confess ); sub f { croak "bah"; } f();` This produces some less-than-useful output when you wrap it with your code.

Comment: You got an idea. I showed the shortest way that could be improved.

Comment: The only changes you made were to introduce bugs, including a third I hadn't noticed before: Your version warns with "subroutine redefined"! Definitely not an improvement.

Comment: Look at my secret solvation above. The topic is closed for me.
`sub test:json_input( 0 , 2 ):json_output`

Comment: What? _________

Comment: You banned my second question when you didn't red it. And today I've seen this question right formed. You know. Just, stop moking.

Comment: I did not mock you. I pointed out the problems with your answer in the hopes that you would fix them, and for future readers if you don't.

Comment: Then please envistigate it. But do not bother me only. I need only to get answers when I had question. Either, I'll answer when I can.

Comment: And I'll comment if you post, as you call it, "shit". Have a nice day.

Comment: With 2nd question. The 2nd question formally was another question, if you didn't had an opinion when the Universe could be understood by one single athom.

Comment: Since you feel so intent on being vitriolic, I take it back. Don't have a nice day.

Comment: OK. I'll rename "shit" into "nihel".

Comment: My timezone is enemy GMT+3 (коммунисты, красные, Крым, наступление).
So, you can write: "Evil night."
.. have an evil nigh..

Comment: Please stop spamming

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As you forgot, I asked, but the answer was only for thouse who interested. Here is no suitable answers from others, but poo or smthing like. I do not like to visit this site.